# Indicators not working but hazards are. Still doesn't work after replacing fuse

Tags: fuse, citroen, fuse-panel, indicators

[image: Fuse diagram from the manual]

**Car**

Citroen C1 1.0 VT 2009

**Symptoms**

- Indicators not working. The stalk does not light up the dashboard
  lights or the actual indicator lights but pressing the hazard button
  does work for both.
- Initially the hazard button did not work until pressed harder than normal but worked fine with a normal press after this instance.
- The left indicator light on the dashboard is a little bit dim

I'm not sure if the last 2 points relate to my main issue but I thought it might be helpful for a diagnosis.

**Detailed Description**

I noticed last night that my indicator was not working at all when pressed up or down. However, the hazards do seem to work. At first when I was pressing down on the hazard, it didn't work initially but I tried a couple more times and pressed the button deeper and it seemed to have worked. Any time after then just seems to work after pressing once normally.

Anyway, I checked the fuse labelled as 5 on the diagram. I don't know much about cars but from what I saw, the fuse looked okay. The car provided some spare fuses anyway, labelled B on that diagram. I tried it with the same colour and rating, still nothing. I then decided to buy new assorted set from Amazon incase the replacement somehow have blown, which it didn't seem like it but it was cheap and good to have. [This is the set that I got](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07CR1MTMY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

I've just tried again now with the new fuse and it still does not work. What else can I do to further diagnose the issue? Or is it best to just be taken to get looked at? As I said, I don't know much about cars but i'm willing to try, so long as I'm comfortable trying whatever it is needs to be done next.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sounds like the switch or connections up to the switch.

Comment: IIRC, the hazard lights are on a separate circuit from the turn signals. They go through the brake circuit in most vehicles, so would have no bearing on the turn signals working. I'm with Mike on this in that it is probably in the multifunction switch, though most of the time when this is the problem, it will show itself as one side or the other and not both sides at the same time.